# what is the $DBSERVER and how to configure in config.php?

Tags: php, database

Hello guys this is my config.php file i am using xampp localhost.  i do not know what is DBServer and how to configure here??? thanks

```
<? 
define(Site_Name,"Welcome to site name ");
 define(Site_Title,"Welcome to site name");
 $SITE_NAME="Welcome to site name ";
 $SITE_URL="http://localhost/test";
 $DBSERVER = "  ?     ";  
 $DATABASENAME = "test";
 $USERNAME = "test";
  $PASSWORD = "012562555";
  $ADMIN_MAIL="";
  $SITE_TITLE=Food order;
  ?>
```

Comment: I am using Xampp localhost so what i can add in DBSERVER ??

Comment: thanks for reply but I did still not working

Comment: I get this error Notice: Undefined variable: DBSERVER in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\adminpanel\index.php on line 11

Comment: I did like this <? 
define(Site_Name,"Welcome to test");
define(Site_Title,"Welcome to test");
$SITE_NAME="Welcome to test";
$SITE_URL="http://localhost/test/";
$DBSERVER = "127.0.0.1";
$DATABASENAME = "db643586389";
$USERNAME = "db643586389";
$PASSWORD = "db643586389";
$ADMIN_MAIL="";
$SITE_TITLE=VIN;
?> but i get this error notice undefined variable:DBserver,....

Answer (score 0):

Just add on:

```
<?php
   $DBSERVER = "127.0.0.1";  
  ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved; please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)